# SMTPlib unresponsive in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

I'm trying to automate sending some emails through Python. However, I'm having some trouble trying to connect to my email server.

Here's the code I have:

```
import smtplib
smptObj = smtplib.SMTP("webmail.incometax.gov.in",465)
print(smptObj.ehlo)
```

However, when I try this, I get literally no response. My terminal (or Atom Script Package) just gives no result and hangs until I `control+Z` to override.

I don't understand why this particular server is throwing up an error, particularly when `smtpObj=smtplib.SMTP("webmail.incometax.gov.in",465)` works.

I'm getting the details for this particular server from https://webmail.incometax.gov.in/iwc_static/layout/docs/webmail-config.html?3.0.0.0.1_020745 These details definitely work for setting up the account on the Gmail app, so I figured that the SMTPlib can also handle sending emails from this server.

Edit/Update: I got the following error message. Can someone help explain to me what is going wrong? Especially since smtp.gmail.com works so well

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jvalin/Desktop/hello.py", line 13, in <module>
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('webmail.incometax.gov.in', 465)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
[Finished in 597.573s]
```

Comment: What do you think the `ehlo` method contains and why do you want to `print` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 465 is usually for secure connections, so your code needs to use [smptlib.SMTP_SSL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL):

```py
smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port)
```